# change sequence vtiger basic field in contact add form

Tags: vtiger

I want that field should enter first and then other field . i am try through move the location in edit layout option and save the sequences. but when i click on add contact the set sequence not view in create contact form.

can you guide thee process for change the sequences of basic field .

Thanks & regards

Nitesh Shah

Answer (score 0):

if you are not bale to change the field order from layout editor, then change the value of column "sequence" in vtiger_field table